# Pixellib - removing background takes huge processing

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, pixellib

I am using Pixellib library in Python to detect a person and change its background, as shown in their example [here](https://pixellib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/change_image_bg.html).

It works flawlessly, but takes huge processing power on my laptop, coupled with their large (~150mb) pascalvoc model, thus rendering an image in approx 4-5sec.

I need to be able to do the same via a mobile phone app, so certainly this cannot be run on a user's mobile. Alternative is to run this on cloud and return the processed image back. This is both costly if user requests increase and will still have noticable lag on user's app.

So, how do achieve this? Apps like [Canva Pro](https://www.canva.com/pro/background-remover/) seem to do this seamlessly in an app [fairly quickly](https://static-cse.canva.com/video/753559/02_CANVA_ProFeatures_BackgroundRemover.mp4). In fact, there are many other 'free' apps on Play store claiming to do the same.

Thus, is there a better way to run Pixellib, to make it more performant? Or any other library that can provide similar (or better) ouptut and can be run on user's mobile?

Comment: Maybe you could give OpenCV's [GrabCut](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) algorithm a try. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67478981/12728244) an example of the algorithm in action. Another tip for speeding up the process involves downscaling the image, get a foreground mask, upscale the mask and apply it to the original image.

Answer (score -3):

There is [remove.bg](https://remove.bg)
It is the most easy tool,to remove background automatically 
Sample code:-https://www.remove.bg/api#sample-code
Screenshots:
[image: Picture]
[image: picture2]
Here is an example of doing in Python:

```
# Requires "requests" to be installed (see python-requests.org)
import requests

response = requests.post(
'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg',
files={'image_file': open('/path/to/file.jpg', 'rb')},
data={'size': 'auto'},
headers={'X-Api-Key': 'INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'},
)
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    with open('no-bg.png', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.content)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

Since your are using `python` ,
This https://github.com/brilam/remove-bg by @brilam will help you.
It is a Python API wrapper for removing backgrounds from picture using remove.bg's API.
But it also offers `go` based command line tool:-https://github.com/remove-bg/go

---

> In addition to that, there are many other opensource library for python in GitHub for your reference: 
>  https://github.com/topics/background-removal?l=python

> Also, you can try, 
> https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg

> OR, refer research paper for your understanding: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09007.pdf

Comment: The terms of use for Remove.bg say "The Operator has the right to restrict the use of the Platform without giving reasons or to block Users.". I wouldn't count on it for any critical uses :)

Comment: @ hifi tech The answer would be better, if you suggest what is in that link -- short summary or screenshot. The current answer is not more useful.

Comment: added some pictures

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem OP has brought forward. He asks "is there a better way to run Pixellib, to make it more performant? Or any other library that can provide similar (or better) output?"

Comment: yes this library gives better output